# Currency Conversion Issue using if else statements result in 0

Tags: java, if-statement, casting, double

when multiplying by doubles smaller than 0 such as yen to dollars conversion it results in 0. I attempted to use cast operators and force the conversion to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

```
     else if(pick == 3){
            if(pick2 == 1){
            monz2 = (double)monz * (double)0.00967135;
            }
            if(pick2 == 2){
            monz2 = (double)monz * (double)0.00787155;
            }
            }
            if(pick2 == 4){
            monz2 = (double)monz * (double)0.00881142;
            }
```

1 = Dollars, 2 = pound, 3 = Yen, 4 = Euro in the pick situation.
I was told to use if else statements in order to create the options as well as formatting the solution.
monz is user input value
monz2 is the output after the conversion.

in the final version of the code all of these calculations result in 0 with or without cast operators.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the data type you are using for monz2.

try this :

```
 int dollar = 10;
double yen = dollar*0.00967135;
System.out.println(yen);
```

Comment: the datatype is already a double for the money being converted/what its converted to (monz/monz2 are doubles) the only use of int was 1-4 in deciding which country to convert from.

Comment: You don't have to put double in front of a number. If ita double why are you typecasting it.It works fine I ran the program.

Answer (score 0):

Found The actual issue messed up if statement nesting. So, if (pick==1) is false, none of the other pick options gets tested. Thanks for the help.